# Unable to plot the determinant function (Possible bug in CoefficientArrays?)

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, warning-messages

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Data*)
L1 = 4;
L2 = 4;
Iyy1 = (0.1*0.1^4)/12;
Iyy2 = (0.1*0.1^4)/12;
A1 = 0.1*0.1;
A2 = 0.1*0.1;
ρ1 = 7850;
ρ2 = 7850;
Y1 = 2*10^11;
Y2 = 2*10^11;
b1 = Surd[(ρ1*A1*ω^2*L1^4)/(Y1*Iyy1), 4];
b2 = Surd[(ρ1*A2*ω^2*L2^4)/(Y2*Iyy2), 4];
λ1 = Sqrt[(A1*L1^2)/Iyy1];
λ2 = Sqrt[(A2*L2^2)/Iyy2];
v1 = FullSimplify[Surd[b1^4/λ1^2, 4]];
v2 = FullSimplify[Surd[b2^4/λ2^2, 4]];
(*Beam Functions*)
W1 = FullSimplify[
   C1*Cos[b1*x1] + C2*Sin[b1*x1] + C3*Cosh[b1*x1] + C4*Sinh[b1*x1]];
W2 = FullSimplify[
   C5*Cos[b2*x2] + C6*Sin[b2*x2] + C7*Cosh[b2*x2] + C8*Sinh[b2*x2]];
(*Bar function*)
U1 = FullSimplify[C9*Cos[v1*x1] + C10*Sin[v1*x1]];
U2 = FullSimplify[C11*Cos[v2*x2] + C12*Sin[v2*x2]];

(*Boundary condition*)
e1 = FullSimplify[W1 /. x1 -> 0];
e2 = FullSimplify[(D[W1, {x1, 1}]) /. x1 -> 0];
e3 = FullSimplify[U1 /. x1 -> 0];
e4 = FullSimplify[W2 /. x2 -> 0];
e5 = FullSimplify[(D[W2, {x2, 1}]) /. x2 -> 0];
e6 = FullSimplify[U2 /. x2 -> 0];

(*Compatability condition*)
(*Displacement contunity*)
e7 = FullSimplify[(W1 /. x1 -> L1) - (U2 /. x2 -> L2)];
e8 = FullSimplify[(W2 /. x2 -> L2) + (U1) /. x1 -> L1];
(*Slope Contunity*)
e9 = FullSimplify[((D[W1, {x1, 1}]) /. 
      x1 -> L1) - ((D[W2, {x2, 1}]) /. x2 -> L2)];
(*Moment Contunity*)
e10 = FullSimplify[((Y1*Iyy1)/L1*((D[W1, {x1, 2}]) /. x1 -> L1)) + ((
      Y2*Iyy2)/L2*((D[W2, {x2, 2}]) /. x2 -> L2))];
(*Force Contuinity*)
e11 = FullSimplify[((Y1*Iyy1)/
      L1^2*((D[W1, {x1, 3}]) /. x1 -> L1)) - (Y2*
      A2 ((D[U2, {x2, 1}]) /. x2 -> L2))];
e12 = FullSimplify[((Y2*Iyy2)/
      L2^2*((D[W2, {x2, 3}]) /. x2 -> L2)) + (Y1*
      A1 ((D[U1, {x1, 1}]) /. x1 -> L1))];
(*Solving*)
R = FullSimplify[
   Normal@CoefficientArrays[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, 
       e11, e12}, {C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, 
       C12}][[2]]];
R1 = MatrixForm[R];
MatrixRank[R];
P = FullSimplify[Det[R]]
Plot[P, {ω, 0, 500}]
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < ω < 500]
s2 = Flatten[ω /. s1];
s3 = s2[[i]];
fn = s3/(2*π)
```

I have a 12  homogenous equation. I have written these equations in `MatrixForm`. And I have taken the `Det` of that matrix `R` which happened to be the function of `Omega`, I tried to plot that function but I am getting the following error `Integer expected at position 2`. So tried the Following
1. Used 'FullSimplify' 
2.Expand
3.TrigReduce
4.TrigExpand
But still, I could not able to solve the issue. I guess maybe I have used `Surd` which leads to the fourth root in the determinant function. How to overcome this error. **This error is stopping me from solving for the roots of determinant function**

Comment: The error is caused by the argument that appears in the Surd function -- it is 4. (a real number) rather than 4 (an integer). One of your evaluations or simplifications is making it real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Minimal example that reproduces error

**Fails**

```
Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1., y, Surd[x, 2]]}, y]
(* {{0.}, {{1. Surd[x, 2.]}}} *)
```

**These do not fail**

```
Normal@CoefficientArrays[Times[1., y, Surd[x, 2]], y]
(* {0, {1. Surd[x, 2]}} *)

Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[y, Surd[x, 2]]}, y]
(* {{0}, {{Surd[x, 2]}}} *)
```

**It may be a bug**, but for whatever reason [`CoefficientArrays`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html) is transforming

```
Surd[x, 2]
```

into

```
Surd[x, 2.]
```

And the evaluation fails because the second arguments is expected to be an integer, and obviously

```
IntegerQ[2.]
(* False *)
```

### Solutions

After

```
R = FullSimplify[
   Normal@CoefficientArrays[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, 
       e11, e12}, {C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, 
       C12}][[2]]];
```

you can patch the result

```
R = (R /. Surd[a_, b_] :> Surd[a, Round[b]])
```

Or use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) as sugested by @CarlWoll in the comments.

```
Block[
 {Surd},
 Normal@CoefficientArrays[
   {Times[1., y, Surd[x, 2]]}
   , y]
 ]
```

Or, see below the suggestion by *Wolfram Support*

```
ClearAttributes[Surd,NumericFunction]
```

### Reply from Wolfram Support

This is the first reply I got for [CASE:4086017]

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I understand that
>   you found a problem in the way Mathematica handles the arguments in 
>   `Normal@CoefficientArrays`. In general, the introduction of finite
>   precision numbers converts everything to finite precision and only if
>   infinite precision is given everywhere than the result is given with
>   infinite precision. The problem that you encountered is generated by
>   the presence of the float number 1. and all coefficients are floating
>   points If integer 1 would be used instead the problem would not appear
>
> ```
> Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1,y,Surd[x,2]]},y]
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
> {{0},{{Surd[x, 2]}}}
> ```
>
> Use of Rationalize function would render all these coefficients as
>   integers
>
> ```
> Rationalize[Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1.,y,Surd[x,2]]},y]]
> ```
>
> gives
>
> ```
> {{0.},{{1. Surd[x, 2.]}}}
> ```
>
> Best regards,
>
> Wolfram Technical Support
>   Wolfram Research Inc.

And then on further communication

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.  Thank you for
>   clarifying the issue. Indeed the presence of a finite precision
>   arguments transforms all arguments into finite precision ones leading
>   to unintended consequence of changing all arguments to lowest
>   precision. This includes arguments that must be integers. `Surd[]` has
>   `NumericFunction` as `Attribute`. Clearing it prevents this type of
>   argument type changing.
>
> ```
> Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1.,y,Surd[x,2]]},y]/.{x->0.5}
> ```
>
> returns an error
>
> > Surd::int: Integer expected at position 2 in Surd[0.5, 2.]. {{0.},
> >     {{1. Surd[0.5, 2.]}}}
>
> while
>
> ```
> ClearAttributes[Surd,NumericFunction]
> Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1.,y,Surd[x,2]]},y]/.{x->0.5}
> ```
>
> returns the numerical evaluations
>
> ```
> {{0.},{{0.707107}}}
> ```
>
> I filed a report to our developers to consider this.

Comment: But why it is changing to  `Surd[x,2.]` when I am clearly defining itas `Surd[x,2]`. I used this function before it was working.

Comment: As I said, **It may be a bug** in Mathematica. Let's see what the other people say.

Comment: Actually, the magic patch you suggested is working, Now I can `Plot` determinant. But `NSolve` is still not working

Comment: @vijay well, try to find the problem yourself, if you can't then that should become a different questions.

Comment: I traced the problem down to ``GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList`` which for inexact input replaces all `NumericQ` and `NumericFunction` objects to approximate form.  Try *e.g.* ``GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[Times[1., y, Surd[x, 2]], {y}]``.  My opinion is that this is buggy behavior.

Comment: Another workaround is `Block[{Surd}, Normal@CoefficientArrays[{Times[1., y, Surd[x, 2]]}, y]]`.